# Debug this backtrack algorithm for Leetcode 46: Permulation problrm?

Tags: python, permutation, backtracking

I'm using the backtracking algorithm to solve the classical. [Leetcode permutation problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/description/).

> Given an array `nums` of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order.

It's pretty straightforward, and I can solve it using the following
code:

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        solutions = []
        def backtrack(state):
            # print(state)
            # print(remain)
            if len(state) == len(nums):
                solutions.append(state.copy())
                # return

            for n in nums:
                if n not in set(state):
                    state.append(n)
                    backtrack(state)
                    state.pop()

        state = []
        backtrack(state)
        return solutions
```

However, when I try to also pass the index of the unselected element (named `remain`), see the following:

```
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        solutions = []
        def backtrack(state, remain):
            if len(state) == len(nums):
                solutions.append(state.copy())
                # return

            for i in remain:
                state.append(nums[i])
                remain.remove(i)
                backtrack(state, remain)
                state.pop()
                remain.add(i)

        full_ind = set([i for i in range(len(nums))])
        state = []
        backtrack(state, full_ind)
        return solutions
```

This doesn't work, and I always get redundancy in my solutions. See below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyQp1.png)
I think there must be some stupid mistake I made, but I can't figure it out. Could anyone help me with this? I struggled a lot to understand what happened. Really Appreciate it :) !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: FYI, `set([i for i in range(len(nums))])` can be simplified to just `set(range(len(nums)))`

Comment: You shouldn't modify a set while you're iterating over it.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar, now I know what's the issue!

Comment: You do know about itertools.permutations, right?  As much fun as it is to write your own code, it's simplest to use code that's already been written.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said, you are modifying a list while iterating over it.

Your second snippet works when you change the loop to:

`for i in list(remain):`

Passing remain to the list constructor creates a list from the original set which you can iterate over while modifying the set.